# Local Jenkins install has no Docker rights

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-19.04

I installed Docker (19.03.3) and Jenkins (2.190.2 LTS from https://jenkins.io/download/) on my Ubuntu 19.04 machine. Then I created a pipeline that loads a `Jenkinsfile` from an example Git repository I created. Everything works well until Jenkins instructs Docker to pull an image. The response is that the system does not have permission to do so. I already added my system user to the `docker` group (`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`) and successfully tested `docker pull node:6-alpine` in my terminal. But Jenkins still fails.

Anyone an idea what the problem is? I guess this is not very complicated and rather a typical configuration error.

Jenkins Pipeline Console Output:

```
Started by user John Doe
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git http://repo.myserver.com/john/example-app.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/example-app-builder
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential jenkins
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url http://repo.myserver.com/john/example-app.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://repo.myserver.com/john/example-app.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Credentials for repo.myserver.com.
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- http://repo.myserver.com/john/example-app.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision f578983d6e153b3063e184c8df194dcff6ee39ab (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f f578983d6e153b3063e184c8df194dcff6ee39ab # timeout=10
Commit message: "Add initial Jenkinsfile."
 > git rev-list --no-walk f578983d6e153b3063e184c8df194dcff6ee39ab # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:6-alpine
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/node:6-alpine/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull node:6-alpine
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/create?fromImage=node&tag=6-alpine: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Jenkins does not run with the `dockers` user. It runs with user `jenkins`. The command should therefore be the following in order to allow user `jenkins` to create Docker containers:

`sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins`